# Bootstrap 3.3.7 dropdown not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a dropdown form where you can set in an e-mail and should have to possibility to choose if you have a company.

If you try the dropdown on the following page: [My example page](http://form.mimsi.dk/) - the dropdown is not working. I can see when the page is loading, that the `<ul>` tag is loading very quickly.

Can anybody see what is wrong?

```html
<input placeholder="Email" name="EMAIL" class="mail" type="text" id="mce-EMAIL" required="">
    <span class="icon4"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><br>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Company
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Yes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">No</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you import jQuery?

Comment: I opened your page source code. You didn't create HTML tags and didn't call any js file. Also you put the bootstrap css code inline

Comment: I'd recommend a basic HTML course.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I am working on a big webshop programmed in .net, where the head, body tag etc is rendering itself. So this is just a quick upload. But of course, the jquery was missing. thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all the links to Bootstrap are working. The code bellow is a link to the online version of bootstrap:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```